# Can the css drag attribute be used to move elements around with no drop?

Tags: javascript, css

Can the draggable css be used to just drag an element from one position to another without the drop-in-container part AND without all the javascript to do it?

Comment: What draggable CSS are you talking about?

Comment: Here's a fairly lengthy tutorial on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations).

Answer (score 0):

without javascript it will not be possible to drag elements, the value "draggable" in you e.g. class attribute is just needed for your javascript to indicate that this element is droggable.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to JQuery-based solution? I'm afraid this isn't what the OP is referring to.

Comment: no, it is one way you can go, without any framework or with a specific framework, it depends on you.